# WPF tabswitch/ render takes too much time

Tags: wpf, performance, drawing

I have a WPF application with many tabs.. 
in one tab.. i make a verycomplex vector drawing consisting of thousands of drawing visuals.. (this represents a machine and all elements need to be interactable..)
It takes 3/4 seconds for drawing this for the first time..After the first draw it should be done..

The problem is if i switch to another tab and comeback, it takes atlease 2,3 seconds to show the tabpage with drawing again..  Since there is no redraw, why should it take so much time..?

Comment: Ever figure out how to speed this up?

Comment: No..  bitmapcache from wpf4 is good.. but it could not be applied in our scenario..may be it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

If the component is not going to change, you could call `Freeze()` on it to mark it as done.  Without trying it out I don't know if that would help, but you could give it a shot.

Not all objects are Freezable.  Check out the MSDN documentation for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx

Another thing you could try would be rendering the vector art to a bitmap, and displaying that.  Maybe it makes you feel icky to lose the vector precision, but if you know it's not going to change and it will look the same, what's the harm?  (If you support printing or something that will require a hi-res version, you could always switch back for that operation.)  For info on how to convert a UIElement to a bitmap, check out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx

Comment: thanks for the answer..  bitmapcache in .net4 would have solved the problem. But the application requires that the drawing should be infinitely zoomable so that the operator can see the finer details of the machine by zooming in. In case bitmapcache we have limits on zoom above which the drawing would be pixelated..    
anyway i was wondering why should the tabswitch take time since it was already rendered and there is no need to draw again when we switch the tab and come back..

Comment: I'm not sure why the rendering seems to take longer the second time, but maybe if this is the first window that appears, the WPF layout engine is doing some of the drawing while the window opens, so the first layout seems to be shorter?  The only way to know would be to measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution: You don't really explain what kind of interaction you are doing with the elements, but if all you want to do is zoom and pan, a `RenderTransform` may be good enough (which is more efficient than a `LayoutTransform` and/or moving all the elements individually).  I haven't played around with combining `Freeze()` and a `RenderTransform`, but you may be able to get the desired zooming while reducing the amount of layout WPF has to do.